24 hours needed to transfer domains between servers?
I rent a VPS from Ionos. They are shutting down the old server my account is on. So I need to manually move everything to a new server with the same company.
When removing one of my domains from the old account, I get the following text.

Important! If you want to transfer the domain to IONOS afterward, please wait at least 24 hours. Otherwise, serious errors may occur during the domain transfer.

Having our websites down for 24 hours is a real problem for us. Does anyone know why we would need to wait 24 hours? Could this really cause permanent problems on the new server? Do I really need to wait 24 hours to be safe?
If it makes any difference, these domains are registered on GoDaddy (external domains). And our main domain is hosted on another server altogether, and the websites on this VPS will be subdomains of that main domain.
I am also transferring the SSL certificate.
Update:
If I was moving to a server owned by a new company, I could simply point my domain name servers to the new server and then they would switch whenever they switched. Users would hit the old server until then. However, in this case, I'm staying with the same company and the name servers will not change. I assume this is the reason for the warning.

What exactly are you doing? Domain transfer? Web server switching? Or both? Do you use your own custom DNS servers, or the ones provided by your domain registration provider? A lot of the details are currently missing.

@LexLi: I have several websites on the server. The server is being shut down so I have to move everything. The domains are hosted on GoDaddy, so as long as they point to the new server, they don't change. But I have to remove the domain from the old server. They are telling me to wait 24 hours in between. And then I need to add the domain to the new server. I'm not sure what a custom DNS server is, so I'm pretty sure the answer to that is no.

DNS is so heavily cached that yes 24 hours or more for changes (update or delete) to get to every host is possible. If you managed every client host, you might log into each and speed things up by poking the resolver, but it won't work for the internet public so let's assume you cannot.
The same kind of delay that you know about from switching providers. This provider only describes the use case of migrating DNS to them, for whatever reason.
If I were to make up names and addresses, let's say you have  www.example.net  with IP of  2001:db8:116:3366::1  plus  stuff.example.net  and things.example.net on  2001:db8:116:3366::2.  The "2" server is being replaced with  "3".
Check if the web site or applications save any state, as in if they use a database. If the host the database runs on changes, execute a cutover at a specific time and only have one copy running at once.  Otherwise, you could introduce logical corruption with some clients on one copy and others on another.
Keep the service names for the applications  (the domains, "stuff and things" in my example) the same.  Have copies of the web site or applications running on both.  Change the DNS records  ("2" to "3") when ready to switch, whether that is an edit or a delete create operation.  Because the end user name is unchanged, and the web site is compatible, it won't matter which they access in the time of transition.
If you wish to have a smaller transition window, consider adding a load balancer in front.  A simpler service on another host that reverse proxies to multiple back end (web) servers.  Hopefully on a different host, so host maintenance operations happen at a different time.  Maybe use managed load balancer from the provider, so they provide the high availability, freeing you from caring about which server it runs on.

"Heavily cached" is a bit overexaggerated. It takes up to 24 hours if the old data had TTL = 24h, whereas if it had TTL = 1h then it takes up to one hour, and if you had a TTL of 30 seconds then the change should be visible after 30 seconds.

If this is only a web server switching, then you shouldn't change anything on the old web server side (don't remove any domain mapping from there, or you break many end users).
Just change your DNS records to point to the new web server, so that end users are served by the new web server gradually during DNS propagation (~48 hours). You can monitor the traffic to the old web server and shut it down when no one is using it any more.

I assume you are talking about the name servers here. The problem is I'm moving them from an Ionos server to an Ionos server. So it appears the name servers do not change. And I assume this is the reason for the warning.

@JonathanWood No. I meant the web server switching (DNS name server changes almost have zero impact on your services). The warning itself is miserable and might only be explained by Ionos support team.

I even asked if there was any way to just edit the domain so it is referencing the new server. Their support told me the only way is to first remove the domain from the old server, and then add it to the new one. Maybe the support guy I talked to is wrong, but that's all I have.

@JonathanWood Since your domain is registered on GoDaddy, you are likely to be using GoDaddy default name servers. Then you usually only need to change the CName (or A) records of the subdomains to point to the new web server IP address, as long as you now have the new web server provisioned. (If you want to test things out without editing DNS records yet, find a spare machine and modify its hosts file.)

No, I needed to set the name servers to the names provided by Ionos. That's what they told me to do. As far as I know, it won't work otherwise.
